# Alternative to Repetitive Try Except Blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a script I wrote to scrape some data there is a chunk of code that looks like this:

```
try:
  prize = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][3]').text
except:
  prize = ''
try:
  field = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][4]').text
except:
  field = ''
try:
  country = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][5]/span[1]/a').get_attribute('title')
except:
  country = ''
try:
  city = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][5]/span[2]').text
except:
  city = ''
try:
  winner = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][6]/span[2]/span').get_attribute('data-highlightingclass')
except:
  winner = ''
try:
  runnerup = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][7]/span[2]/span').get_attribute('data-highlightingclass')
except:
  runnerup = ''
```

I'm new to Python and wondering if there are any alternative or more succinct ways to accomplish this?

Comment: You can create a function and then pass arguments

Comment: `prize = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][3]').text` will not throw an exception even if there is no data in that particular cell. It will return whatever value is present. It will throw exception only if there is no such cell. So you don't need multiple try catch. You need if else.

Comment: @vks but then how do i set the variables? can i create variables with parameters as the variable names?

Comment: You can create parameters for `By.XPATH`, and others.And then replace by them in function code

Comment: @vks i know i can create parameters for those things, but how do i create the variables with unique names? i obviously cannot pass in an argument `def whatever (varName): try: pass except: varName = ''` or i guess i could use a function return to the output and then simply `runnerup = myFunction(arg1, arg2, ...)` but then how do i handle the `get_attribute` and `text` methods separately

Answer (score 0):

**Preamble:** Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you.

I will assume that you are using Selenium.

---

You have different options here.

### One clause to catch them all

If all elements are mandatory, you might as well use one bigger try-catch:

```
try:
    prize = row.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "divCell")][3]').text
    field = row.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "divCell")][4]').text
    country = row.find_element_by_xpath('./div[contains(@class, "divCell")][5]/span[1]/a').get_attribute('title')
    ...
except NoSuchElementException:
    # Do something smart
```

(Note that the Selenium documentation [recommends to](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) use the method `WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath` instead of `WebDriver.find_element` directly.)

### Encapsulation

(As recommended by @vks.)

Instead of using a method that can raise an exception directly, you can wrap around it and return `None` instead:

```
def find_element_by_xpath_or_None(haystack, xpath):
    try:
        return haystack.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
```

And then use it as such:

```
prize = find_element_by_xpath_or_None(row, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][3]')
prize = prize.text if prize else ''

field = find_element_by_xpath_or_None(row, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][4]')
field = prize.text if prize else ''

country = find_element_by_xpath_or_None(row, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][5]/span[1]/a')
country = country.get_attribute('title') if country else ''
```

**Edit:** Also do-able with lambdas.

### Complete encapsulation

You could even make that leaner by using lambdas to explicitly state what to extract:

```
def find_element_by_xpath_or_None(haystack, xpath, access_fun):
    try:
        return access_fun(haystack.find_element_by_xpath(xpath))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
```

And:

```
field = find_element_by_xpath_or_None(
    row, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][4]',
    lambda e: e.text
) or ''

country = find_element_by_xpath_or_None(
    row, './div[contains(@class, "divCell")][5]/span[1]/a',
    lambda e: e.get_attribute('title')
) or ''
```

Comment: all elements arent mandatory, which is implicit in my MVP. the encapsulation that you suggested is pointless since it requires even more code and even more calculations. im not exactly sure what lambdas are yet sooo unsure about that but it seems to be the only one possibly with potential

Comment: (Sorry but no, your example is not an MVP, we cannot reproduce without the data and without the right imports.)

Comment: The encapsulation proposal allows to factor out the same behaviour and then offers a syntax that I believe is more readable. If this is not what you are looking for, please elaborate your question a bit more with what you expect/want. (Lambdas are basically anonymous functions declared as `lambda <parameter>: <expression that will be returned>`.)

Comment: it is indeed an MVP in the sense that my question doesnt concern any of the surrounding data whatsoever, but rather that particular pattern of code

Comment: Ah I see, you are right. Still, I second @vks' proposal in that wrapping your error handling makes sense since it is always the same error you encounter and that you handle in the same way. (Also, it is best practice to use explicit raise clauses `except NoSuchElementException:` vs. a catch-all `except:`, the code ends up easier to read and more explicit.)

Comment: idk i personally dont think thats the best way to do it. perhaps if this was occurring elsewhere in the script too, but even then its no easier to read and a lot more code and computation. youre right i should be raising specific exceptions but this is just for personal need not production or work